# Accept remote connections to Solr/Jetty instance running on Windows Server 2012

Tags: solr, jetty, windows-server-2012, windows-firewall

I'm running a Solr 4.10.1 Jetty instance on Windows Server 2012.
I'm using the simple example Jetty version that ships with the download, and by running `java -jar start.jar` (from solr-4.10.1\example) I was able to access my Solr instance from the Windows Server via `http://localhost:8983/solr`.

Now I want to access the Solr/Jetty instance remotely, i.e. from another computer. I.e. I want to be able to access the Solr instance running on my Windows Server via HTTTP calls to `http://<server IP>:8080/solr` and/or `http://<server_domain>:8080/solr` from a remote client/computer.

I've created an inbound Firewall rule on my Windows Server, accepting any remote address on local port 8080, and I've changed the jetty port on the jetty.xml to 8080, which works fine (I can access the Solr instance on `http://localhost:8080/solr` from my Windows Server). 
But when I try to change the jetty host to the IP of the server, I can't access the Solr core  collection any more - i.e. there are no collections in the core selector, so I cannot perform any queries on `'http://<server IP>/solr/#/collection1/'` - I only see a "blank" Solr interface.

The part of the jetty.xml I changed looks like this:

```
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
        <Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" default="<WINDOWS_SERVER_IP>"/></Set>
        <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">50000</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourceMaxIdleTime">1500</Set>
        <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

First of all - is this the correct approach? If yes, what am I doing wrong? If no, how can I achieve it? I've tried to search for ways to do this, but I can't seem to find any good resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is resolved. I had to do two additional things:
1. Make Jetty use the special IP 0.0.0.0 to have it listen on all interfaces:

```
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
        <Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" default="<0.0.0.0>"/></Set>
        <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">50000</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourceMaxIdleTime">1500</Set>
        <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

2. Open HTTP traffic on port 8080 **from** clients **to** server on the domain firewall.

Now Solr is accessible on `http://SERVER_DOMAIN_NAME:8080/solr` for all machines connected in this domain.

Comment: I have the same problem on `Solr 8.11.1`, but there is no such section with `SocketConnector` in my `jetty.xml`. Where should this be added? Maybe inside the section of `<New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">`?

Comment: I found this, but adding IPs in the whitelist doesn't seem to work either for some reason: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_5/securing-solr.html#enable-ip-access-control