# Solr access remotely using default Jetty installation

Tags: solr, jetty, settings, public

I've tried for hours to configure Solr to be accessible remotely (from another network) using the default Jetty installation it comes with. I tinkered with almost every setting imaginable and failed to see results. So i've reached the conclusion that i'm missing something.

What would be the proper way to make Solr accessible publicly using Jetty? I'm using Solr 8.10.0
Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Solr does not actively limit where you can reach it from, if you cannot get to it from another network then it is likely a firewall rule that is in your way not anything in the solr setup.

Comment: What port is your Solr running under? Are you sure that port is open to the outside?

Comment: Solr is using port 8983 and i'm on Debian 7, it's an old machine that i do not own. I have configured iptables to accept input/output on this port to no avail. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a similar problem with version 8.11.1. I can access Solr, getting the correct server certificate and all, but the page says `HTTP ERROR 403 Forbidden`. For my case, it is certainly not a firewall issue.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835846/accept-remote-connections-to-solr-jetty-instance-running-on-windows-server-2012

Answer (score 0):

People that commented on this were correct. It was a firewall issue and unrelated to Solr. The port was closed by a hardware-level firewall that i was not aware of.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).